# How do I make Syntastic work with the Dockerfile plugin?

Tags: vim, dockerfile, syntastic

I use the vim plugins [Syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic) and [Dockerfile.vim](https://github.com/ekalinin/Dockerfile.vim).

Syntastic has some checkers now for (lower-case) `dockerfile` file types, which is a built-in filetype for vim, but with only rudimentary syntax support.  The better support with the Dockerfile.vim plugin sets a file type of (upper-cased) `Dockerfile`, which isn't detected by Syntastic.

I can locally tweak the Syntastic installation to copy the `dockerfile` checker directory to `Dockerfile`, and make a few associated case changes in the checker, but that seems clumsy.

Maybe there's a way to mess with my filetype detection so I simultaneously get the benefit of both plugins?  Maybe `Dockerfile.vim` should be building on/replacing the `dockerfile` filetype, and not adding a new `Dockerfile`?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, there is a better way, but it's only available to people who read the manual: `:h 'syntastic_filetype_map'`.

Comment: Aw, harsh.  I did try, but clearly not hard enough.  I missed that.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this could be referenced in the FAQ's 4.1?  Which I certainly did read, many times.

Comment: It isn't a common problem. _shrug_

Comment: @lcd047, wink, wink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per lcd047's comment above, Use `syntastic_filetype_map`:

> `*'syntastic_filetype_map'* Type: dictionary Default: {} Use this option to map non-standard
>   filetypes to standard ones.  Corresponding checkers are mapped
>   accordingly, which allows syntastic to check files with non-standard
>   filetypes: >
>       let g:syntastic_filetype_map = {
>           \ "plaintex": "tex",
>           \ "gentoo-metadata": "xml" }`

So: `let g:syntastic_filetype_map = {"Dockerfile": "dockerfile"}`